# Eating inside the restaurant

Tags: phrases

We all know that if we want to *eat outside the restaurant* we say "***take away***", but what about if you want to *eat inside*? Do you say to the cashier "***eating here***"?

Is there a common phrase ?

Comment: No - if you go to a restaurant that has tables, it is assumed you are eating there, unless you specifically ask for the take-away menu.

Comment: In the US, we don't usually say "take-away."  We say "take-out."  If it's a counter restaurant, the server will usually ask, "For here or to go?" and then put your food into a bag or on a tray.  Another way of saying this is "To stay or to go?"  At a sit-down restaurant where there is a large take-out business, the host(ess) might ask, "Eat in or take out?"

Answer (score 10):

If you want to eat inside the restaurant and while ordering on the counter if cashier asks, we can say "***eat in***", which is British Antonym of "take away" as stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/takeaway).

Also, ***Dine in*** is a strong word which is used for such situation.

Comment: It's also the American antonym of "take out".

Comment: Yeah, I found _take out_ also at many places. Thanks for updating my knowledge.. :)

Comment: "Will that be takeaway, or are you dining in?" is common in Australia (as well as "eating in").